# sql server avg_user_impact

Tags: sql-server, indexing

In the DMV `sys.dm_db_missing_index_group_stats`, there is a field named `avg_user_impact`. Per BOL, this shows the

> Average percentage benefit that user queries could experience if this missing index group was implemented. The value means that the query cost would on average drop by this percentage if this missing index group was implemented.

When I run a query to find the missing indexes that would have the greatest impact on performance, I see a few that claim the `avg_user_impact` will be in the thousands.

I built an index using one of these recommendations, and it was never used according to the DMV `sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats`. As soon as I disabled the index, it immediately showed up again as a missing index.

Is it possible that once the `avg_user_impact` field shows over 100, it's in error? Or is this an example of how a recommended index must still be tested for usefulness? What am I doing wrong or misunderstanding?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The recommended indexes and user impact are both estimates from the cost optimizer, and, as you see there's no guarantee that they are always correct. I think the user impact column can be over 100 by design (though we'd have to hope a MS developer from the SQL Server team is responding here for the real answer.) It is always vital to test whether creating the indexes shown in the DMV will work or not. I have had the same experience where an index is shown there, but once created doesn't actually get used, perhaps due to the details of the query or the data distribution in the tables, etc. The view is right most of the time, especially for simple cases, but not always.

Also, be careful about creating really wide indexes, as they might hurt insert/update performance more than they help select performance, depending on how busy the server is.

Comment: One other thing - there's a really clever query to correlate query plans against recommended indexes here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqldatabaseengine/thread/71814032-cd8d-4802-80de-7fb2bee80f41 
also:
http://sqlblog.com/blogs/jonathan_kehayias/archive/2009/07/27/digging-into-the-sql-plan-cache-finding-missing-indexes.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Table Statistics also has to be updated to make sure SQL Engine use the newly created Indexes.

After creating indexes RUN

USE AdventureWorks2012;
GO
EXEC sp_updatestats;
GO

Update STATISTICS command will make sure that all cached SQL plan are invalidated and new sql execution plans are built using the newly created indexes.

Comment: Hi, Mayank. Your statement might not be fully correct. Here is another stackoverflow post that should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1930726/are-statistics-automatically-updated-when-a-new-index-is-created