# Are statistics automatically updated when a new index is created?

Tags: sql-server, indexing, statistics

Is there any benefit to running an UPDATE Statistics after you create an index or is it done automatically for you?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the new index needs new statistics they are automatically created, unless you explictly disable the statistics compute for the new index via `CREATE INDEX ... WITH STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = ON`

Answer (score 2):

Om 2005, at least, they are created automatically with `CREATE INDEX`:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc966419.aspx#XSLTsection129121120120