# UPDATE STATISTICS after CREATE INDEX?

Tags: sql-server-2008

When I create an index on SQL Server 2008 R2 do i need to run update statistics after?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are statistics automatically updated when a new index is created?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1930726/are-statistics-automatically-updated-when-a-new-index-is-created)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you do not need to update statistics immediately after creating index.
When you create index, statistics are created with 100% of data. Running update statistics with default setting will overwrite it with sample.

As you data change (insert/update/delete) you will need to periodically update statistics to make sure your changes are reflected in your statistics.  If you auto update statistics is on it will update itself when 20%+500 row changes, using sample.  If sample is not good enough for your application you can consider manual update statistics.